# How to play the next video after the first video had finish for IOS5 application/ NOT LOADING WEB VIDEO

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, video, continuous

So how do you play a video straight after one video finishes playing on iphone. I put this

NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

but dunno what else to put after that to play another video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are running local video i.e from your app then you probably will knowing the name of them.
save all the video name in an array.

create a function that will be doing all your movie playing stuff and accepta a filepath/url or the name of your video file.

you can use `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` to know whether the video finished playing.

once you know that call the same function that plays the video again and pass the filepath/name to it. It will again start playing your next video.

Hope that help

Comment: So an example of an array *videoUrl = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"big-buck-bunny-clip", @"moon_walk", nil];
    
    NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:*videoUrl ofType:@"m4v"];                               and then call it like this?